# Where I can find classifications of Lie algebra $A_{4.7}^{-1}$?

Tags: lie-algebras

My Lie algebra with commutation relation

> $[e_2, e_3] = e_3,\;[e_2, e_4] = -e_4,\;[e_3, e_4] = -e_1$

is isomorphic to Lie algebra $A_{4.7}^{-1}$ through transformations

> $e_1\mapsto e_1,\;e_2\mapsto - e_4,\;e_3\mapsto e_3,\;e_4\mapsto e_2$

I tried to find classification of algebra $A_{4.7}^{-1}$ in [Patera and Winternitz](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/18/7/10.1063/1.523441) but there I find only classification of $A_{4.7}$.

Can anybody please suggest me article where classification of $A_{4.7}^{-1}$ is given ?

Comment: How is $A_{4.7}^{-1}$ defined ?

Comment: Roman Popovych suggested me this algebra, I don't know this algebra either.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Actually I was reading paper `Realizations of Real Low-Dimensional Lie Algebras` by Roman O. Popovych and I asked him query about realization of algebra $[e_2, e_3] = e_3,\;[e_2, e_4] = -e_4,\;[e_3, e_4] = -e_1$ and he responded with algebra $A_{4.7}^{-1}$, unfortunately I don't know how this algebra is different from $A_{4.7}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lie algebra is exactly $A_{4,8}^{-1}$ in Roman Popovych's [classification](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0301029v7.pdf), page $17$, Table $5$, after the suggested base change. The Lie brackets are given by
$$
[x_2,x_3]=x_1,\;[x_2,x_4]=x_2,\;[x_3,x_4]=-x_3.
$$
So Roman Popovych is right. There only was a typo in the index, it seems.